# Using save to create a new file with user's input (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, input, save

I'm making a code, and I've used the input function to get the name the user wants for the new file, but I do not know how to use save with said name.

I've tried something like this:

```
matrix = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]
name = input ('Name your new file > ', 's')
save ('name.txt', 'matrix' )
```

which obviously creates a file with the name 'name'..
Thanks!

Comment: `save (name, 'matrix' )` or `save (strcat(name,'.txt'), 'matrix' )`

Comment: @Weather Vane you can post this as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`save (strcat(name,'.txt'), 'matrix' )` didn't work for me, the file was created but didn't have `matrix` in it.

I could get the desired results with the following code,

```
matrix = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
name = input ('Name your new file > ', 's');
dlmwrite([name,'.txt'],matrix, 'delimiter', '\t','newline', 'pc');
```

Comment: Yeah that way the file does not appear just as code, you can actually see the matrix. But what if what I wanted to save were words not numbers? How you you do that?

Comment: @peronsintra if the `matrix` is like `matrix = ['a' 'b' 'c'; 'd' 'e' 'f'];` then it works, what is your `matrix`? you can edit the question.

Comment: it's not a matrix but a text file with different words (I think matlab does not let you do a matrix with words cause of the dimensions?)

Comment: @peronsintra, yes, you should use `cell`.

Comment: @peronsintra try `matrix = {'ad' 'b  ' 'cfg';'d ' 'ert' 'fqa'};` and use `cell2mat(matrix)` with `dlmwrite`.

Comment: @peronsintra, do you have to use `text`? can't you use `mat`? that's very easier.

Comment: indeed it is! Nonetheless I have to use both. In your opinion is it bad if I use the save function with strcat for the text (not the matrix), as it was suggested the first time around? It does the trick but the user can't see for himself the text.. Although he can use 'importdata' if he wishes to see it.

Comment: @peronsintra, It depends how your text is placed in cell, if `mat` is okey then use `save (name, 'matrix' )`, `matrix` being cell of string and use `load` or `improtdata` to read.